# Python Hierarchical Clustering Inconsistency: What do the outputs for the inconsistent mean

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchy

I'm trying to learn how to use the **scipy.cluster.hierarchy.inconsistent**. I know from the [document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.inconsistent.html) and this [one](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/inconsistent.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) that the first column and the second column represent mean and standard deviation respectively; the third means the number of links, and the fourth is the inconsistency coefficient.
However, what I don't understand is that:

1. what does the **all the links included in the calculation** really mean?
2. what does the **d parameter** of **scipy.hierarchy.cluster.inconsistent(Z, d=2)** really do?

For example, let's assume that we have X matrix as follow:

```
[[2], [8], [0], [4], [1], [9], [9], [0]]
```

Then, get the Z value by

```
Z = linkage(X, 'single')
```

And, we get

```
[[  2.   7.   0.   2.]
 [  5.   6.   0.   2.]
 [  0.   4.   1.   2.]
 [  8.  10.   1.   4.]
 [  1.   9.   1.   3.]
 [  3.  11.   2.   5.]
 [ 12.  13.   4.   8.]]
```

Finally, get the inconsistency

```
inconsistent(Z)
```

The output is

```
[[ 0.       0.       1.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       1.       0.     ]
 [ 1.       0.       1.       0.     ]
 [ 0.66667  0.57735  3.       0.57735]
 [ 0.5      0.70711  2.       0.70711]
 [ 1.5      0.70711  2.       0.70711]
 [ 2.33333  1.52753  3.       1.09109]]
```

For the fourth row, which three links are used to calculate the mean and standard deviation to get the value of **0.66667** and **0.57735** exactly?

```
[ 0.66667  0.57735  3.       0.57735]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to understand the Z matrix:

```
[[  2.   7.   0.   2.] <== x[2] is linked with x[7], forming cluster x[8] = {x[2], x[7]}
 [  5.   6.   0.   2.]
 [  0.   4.   1.   2.] <== x[10] = {x[0], x[4]}
 [  8.  10.   1.   4.] <== x[11] = {x[8], x[10]} = {x[2], x[7], x[0], x[4]}
 [  1.   9.   1.   3.]
 [  3.  11.   2.   5.]
 [ 12.  13.   4.   8.]]
```

There are 3 links included in the calculation of the fourth row:

```
|     Link       | Height/Distance |
| x[2] - x[7]    |   Z[0,2] = 0    |
| x[0] - x[4]    |   Z[2,2] = 1    |
| x[8] - x[10]   |   Z[3,2] = 1    |
```

The mean value of (1,1,0) is `R[3,0] = 0.66667`, and the standard deviation is `R[3,1] = 0.57735` (normalized by N-1, not N). The inconsistent value is computed as:

```
           Z[i,2] - R[i,0]      1 - 0.6667
R[i,3]  =  ---------------  =   ----------  =  0.57735
              R[i,1]             0.57735
```

> 1. what does the all the links included in the calculation really mean?
> 2. what does the d parameter of scipy.hierarchy.cluster.inconsistent(Z,
>      d=2) really do?

For a cluster C, all the links below the cluster C, up to depth d, are considered to compute statistics (mean and std). In the above example, d=2 means we look at the link that created x[11] (depth 1), and the links below x[8] and x[10] (depth 2).

Comment: How you are calculating `Height/Distance` ?. Also the `mean value of (1,1,0) is R[3,0] = 0.66667`. What is R[3,0]?